# Platform-specific dependencies of portable class libraries

Tags: portable-class-library

I have a piece of code that compiles for both the Silverlight and the .NET targets. It depends on Json.NET and SharpZipLib. My goal is to make a portable library that Silverlight and .NET projects can both link against.

Since there is no version of SharpZipLib targeting "portable-net40+sl50", I have a problem.

However, if I knew how, I would be willing to write the wrapper code myself.

So: How can I write a portable library that depends on Silverlight's SharpZipLib when being linked against from Silverlight and depends on .NET's SharpZipLib when being linked against from .NET?

Is that at all possible or is that something only Microsoft can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code uses a limited sub-set of the *SharpZipLib* API, you could create a "dummy" PCL library comprising this API subset, but without any functionality implemented.

What you then must do is to change the strong name (assembly name and signing) and version of the existing .NET and Silverlight *SharpZipLib*:s to be the same as your "dummy" PCL *SharpZipLib* and re-compile the platform specific libraries as well.

With this set of assemblies (PCL, .NET and Silverlight) you will now be able to consume the PCL library from other PCL libraries. In a platform specific application that makes use of PCL libraries that in turn consumes the *SharpZipLib* library, you should explicitly reference the platform specific *SharpZipLib* library that has the same strong name and version as the PCL analogue.

You should find more about this technique ("bait-and-switch") [here](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx). The [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) project is also a good example of where this technique has been applied.